# Strange Input Behavior on Opening Laptop Lid

Tags: keyboard, suspend, laptop, input-devices

I'm running 16.04, and I'm using the XMonad environment, though I don't think that's the issue here.

When I open my laptop lid, I am prompted for my password to unlock my computer, which I can type and enter, but then after I am logged in, text input no longer seems to work. Cursors don't appear in text boxes, and no keyboard input works at all. Then, if I re-close and open the lid, a variety of strange things can happen, such as my keyboard working, but then my mouse not, or sometimes neither.

Is there some background process that's not getting restarted? How can I troubleshoot this issue?